# Date sorting of PHP Event

Tags: php, events, sorting, date

I have an events calender that displays events in the order of start date. Everything works great but there is one issue. Events that occur on today's date don't display. I believe that my "if" statement to remove events after they have passed is the issue.

```
<? while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($result)) {
$id = $row['id'];
$title = $row['title'];
$text = $row['text'];
$image_url = $row['image_url'];
$start_date = date('F d, Y', strtotime($row['start_date']));
$start_hour = $row['start_hour'];
$start_minute = $row['start_minute'];
$start_am_pm = $row['start_am_pm'];
$end_date = date('F d, Y', strtotime($row['end_date']));
$end_hour = $row['end_hour'];
$end_minute = $row['end_minute'];
$end_am_pm = $row['end_am_pm'];
$tba = $row['tba'];

if(strtotime($row['end_date']) > date('U')) {
?>
```

Comment: What is your query that is being run, the problem is there.  Also, there is no reason to do `$id = $row['id']`, just use `$row['id']` to keep your code clean and to save yourself time

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all, I just want to point out that:

```
date('U') == time()
```

So you can use `time` instead of `date`.

Now for your problem. If the `end_date` of your event is set to today, it's probably at the beginning of the day (i.e.: 2010-11-18 00:00:00). That's probably why your conditional does not work, because now is past midnight, the current date/time is greater than the `end_date`.

Try this:

```
if (strtotime($row['end_date']) == strtotime('TODAY')) {
    // event is today
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I'm guessing that $row['end_date'] only returns the date not the time.  So `strtotime($row['end_date'])` will = 12:00AM and `date('U')` will equal return the current time.

So if you ran this at 12:01AM on the date of $row['end_date'], you'd have the comparison of

```
if("12:00AM today" > "12:01AM today") {
```

Try

```
if (strtotime($row['end_date']) >= strtotime(date('Y-m-d'))) {
```